# ruby on rails - namespace issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby and I would like some help. I am trying to use namespace to create the url:

```
namespace :work, only: [:index], path: "work/calculators"  do 
    resources :bonus_scheme_calculator, path: "bonus-scheme-calculator" 
end
```

In the end I want the link -> work/calculators/bonus-scheme-calculator to work. 
Unfortunately it shows me an error -> uninitialized constant work

In the end I expect to have a folder in controllers called work with a rb file bonus_scheme_calculator.

Is my logic correct?

Answer (score 0):

`namespace` does not have `only` option

ref: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping/namespace

You should remove that and check again